# Query Performance issues :query case entity (Incident )for Dynamics CRM SSRS Report

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I have written below query for dynamics crm- SSRS Report, but it takes too long time for execution (approx. 6 min).

**Query :**

> select   ticketnumber,  Title,  zon_requeststatusname, 
>   FI.owneridname,  zon_applicationname,  zon_applicationareaname, 
>   LastLogChanged,  zon_requestorname ,  FI.createdon,  FI.createdbyname,
>   isescalatedname,  zon_ordername,  DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),
>   FI.createdon) as AgingPeriod from filteredincident FI left outer join
>   (select  top 1 zon_case, max(createdon) as LastLogChanged from
>   Filteredzon_caselog group by createdon,zon_case order by 2 desc )CL
>   on FI.incidentid= CL.zon_case
>   where DATEDIFF(day,FI.createdon ,GETDATE()) = @CreatedInLast and DATEDIFF(day,FI.modifiedon ,GETDATE()) = @ModifiedSince

**Same Queries without Filtered view :(but don't want to use , because we will loose security benefit)**

> DECLARE @CreatedInLast INT
>   DECLARE @ModifiedSince INT
>   SET @ModifiedSince =  1
>   SET @CreatedInLast =  7
>
> SELECT    ticketnumber,   Title,  zon_requeststatusname,  FI.owneridname,
>     zon_applicationname,    zon_applicationareaname,    --MAX(CL.modifiedon),
>     zon_requestorname ,     FI.createdon,   FI.createdbyname,
>     isescalatedname,    zon_ordername,
>       DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(), FI.createdon) as AgingPeriod FROM filteredincident FI (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN zon_caselog CL (NOLOCK)
>   on FI.incidentid= CL.zon_case AND CL.modifiedon >= GETDATE()-
>   @ModifiedSince    WHERE       FI.createdon  >= GETDATE()- @CreatedInLast
>             GROUP BY    ticketnumber,   Title,  zon_requeststatusname,  FI.owneridname,     zon_applicationname,    zon_applicationareaname,
>     zon_requestorname ,     FI.createdon,   FI.createdbyname,
>     isescalatedname,    zon_ordername

I already run `DBCC DBREINDEX` and `DBCC INDEXDEFRAG`.

Please advise me, what's need to improve above queries.

Comment: I see Nolock is missing in 1st query; still 2nd query uses filteredincident

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filteredview will join the select query with POA table internally to maintain the CRM security model in resultset.

I would recommend you to take a look at the size of PrincipalObjectAccess (POA) table & consider [cleaning](http://dotnetdust.blogspot.com/2014/01/lessons-learned-deleting-312-million.html?m=1) it up.